# how to add items into UIScrollView of UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, uiscrollview

I'm working on a project that requires the use of a `UIWebView`, obviously because I have to work with html. I've added the `UIWebView` from storyboard and his property is `articleWebView`.

However my problem is that I need to enter inside the `UIWebView` some elements that are not present in html (html is get from a json and it isn't editable), as 2 `UILabel` and a `UIImageView`. 
I used this method and it works well

```
    UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 80, 298, 200)];
    [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"myPng.png"]];
//[some code here...]   
    UILabel *articleTitle = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 10, 298, 40)];
    articleTitle.text = @"someText";
//[some code here...]    
    self.articleWebView.delegate = self;
//[some code here...]
    NSString *myHTML = @"<html>myWebContent</html>;
//[some code here...]    
    [self.articleWebView loadHTMLString:myHTML baseURL:nil];
    [self.articleWebView.scrollView addSubview:articleTitle];
    [self.articleWebView.scrollView addSubview:myImage];
```

Within this code the subviews are shown at their x/y axis correctly but the html text didn't be set so its shown at the top of the `UIWebView` at x/y = 0, so to speak, behind the `UIImageView`

do you have any idea how can I move, at a given distance, my `myHTML` below other items??

Comment: Why are you making code complicated ? `UIWebView` is for `HTML` content.

Comment: If you can add break tag `<br>` within your content in HTML string?

Comment: @ tiger thanks for help. @Hemang no i cant add <br> or something else to my HTMLs

Comment: Edit the HTML or inject into it using javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, as you are receiving your HTML as a string, you do can edit it, just appending new HTML strings to it, like you are already doing in this line
 `NSString *myHTML = @"<html>myWebContent</html>;`

You can easily play with strings to achieve what you want. it will be something like this:

```
NSString *header = @"\
    <h1>My title here</h1>\
    <img .../>;\
     ";

NSString *myHTML = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html>%@%@</html>, header, myWebContent];
```